# uWSGI thread has existing running event loop which causes Django's SynchronousOnlyOperation exception

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, uwsgi

I have two Django views,

```
def view_that_accesses_orm(request): # say end point /useorm
  user = User.objects.first()
  ...
```

and

```
def view_that_creates_event_loop(request): # say endpoint /createloop
  client = AsycProvider()
  ... # do stuff with client
```

and `AsyncProvider` is something like

```
class AsyncProvider:
  def __init__(self):
    try:
      self.__loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError as e:
      print(e) #no running event loop
      self.__loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
      asyncio.set_event_loop(self.__loop)
    self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=self.__loop)

  ... # other operations with asyncio.run_until_complete, asyncio.gather, and self.__session
```

Now the issue is that say if I have 1 process in uWSGI and 2 threads. Then they will be in a round robin fashion serving requests.

So scenario is:

1. User hits `/createloop` (given thread 1)
2. User hits `/useorm` (given thread 2)
3. User again hits `/useorm` (given thread 1)

Now in third scenario, sometimes the event loop is running and since Django 3.x detects a running event loop and disallows us to access ORM, I get the `django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.` exception.

I am not sure how the event loop doesn't stop and persist in the thread.

Please explain what exactly could be the cause of this and what should be the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that somewhere inside a method of `AsyncProvider` was using `asyncio.set_event_loop(self.__loop)`.

So the same loop instance was being referenced in different threads (new loop wasn't being created). Now since this loop would sometimes also have some running logic and also if in a thread (which has referenced this loop) ORM was being accessed, Django threw the `SynchronousOnlyOperation` as it could detect running event loop.

Solved it by removing `asyncio.set_event_loop(self.__loop)` in the method.